# Is a given component in view?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

In Ext JS 4, is there a simple way to determine if a component is actually in view?  That is both visible and within the area currently displayed in the browser window.

I am aware of `isVisible()`, which will tell me if it is visible in the DOM, but I would also like to know if the component has been scrolled out of view (and therefore does not need updating visually).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Component.getX()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-getX), [Component.getY()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-getY), [Component.getHeight()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-getHeight), [Component.getWidth()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-getWidth) of your main container and your component and compute that manually (also check the *scroll* methods of the main component).